# Formatting checks against a session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

This is the current code that gets put into a option box, is there a way to make this code more efficient and use less code

```
<select name="searchTypeSelect" id="searchTypeSelect" size='1' class='searchUtilityMenu' >
        <option value='<%# ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingPLUSearch") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["pluNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                  (
                   ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingLabels") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["labelsNumberSearchCaptionValue"] :
                   (
                    ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingTextsSearch") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["textsSearchNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                    (
                     ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingTraceability") ?  WorldViewNet.programming.TextsSearch.textsSearchNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                     (
                      ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingNotBarcodes") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["barcodesNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                      (
                       ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingShops") ? WorldViewNet.programming.Shops.shopsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                       (
                        ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingCustomers") ? WorldViewNet.programming.Customers.customersNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                        (
                         ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingNutrifacts") ? WorldViewNet.programming.Nutrifacts.nutrifactsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                         (
                          ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingIngredients") ? WorldViewNet.programming.Ingredients.ingredientsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                          (
                           ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingServings") ? WorldViewNet.programming.Servings.servingsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                           (
                            ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "programmingImagesSearch") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["imagesSearchNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                            (
                             ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "managementCurrency") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["currencyNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                             (
                              ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceRejector") ? WorldViewNet.service.Rejector.rejectorsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                              (
                               ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemTemplates") ? (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["templatesNumberSearchCaptionValue"] : 
                               (
                                ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "managementTotals") ? WorldViewNet.management.Totals.totalsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                (
                                 ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "managementCookingTimes") ? WorldViewNet.management.CookingTimes.cookingTimesNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                 (
                                  ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "managementTrays") ? WorldViewNet.management.Trays.traysNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                  (
                                   ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "managementAssignMachinePLU") ? WorldViewNet.management.AssignMachinePLU.assignPLUIDSearchCaptionValue : 
                                   (
                                    ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceSettingsGeneral") ? WorldViewNet.service.settings.General.generalNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                    (
                                     ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceSettingsDateTime") ? WorldViewNet.service.settings.DateTime.dateTimeNumberSearchCaptionValue :
                                     (
                                      ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceDevicesLabellers") ? WorldViewNet.service.devices.Labellers.labellersNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                      (
                                       ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceNetworkConnections") ? WorldViewNet.service.NetworkConnections.networkConnectionsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                       (
                                        ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceLabellers1") ? WorldViewNet.service.Labellers.labellersNumberSearchCaptionValue :
                                        (
                                         ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "serviceLabellers") ? WorldViewNet.service.Labellers.labellersNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                         (
                                          ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemSettingsMachine") ? WorldViewNet.system.settings.Machine.machineNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                          (
                                           ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemSystemFields") ? WorldViewNet.system.SystemFields.systemFieldsNumberSearchCaptionValue :
                                           (
                                            ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemCategories") ? WorldViewNet.system.Categories.categoriesNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                            (
                                             ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemDateFormats") ? WorldViewNet.system.DateFormats.dateFormatsNumberSearchCaptionValue : 
                                             (
                                              ((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"] == "systemTimeFormats") ? WorldViewNet.system.TimeFormats.timeFormatsNumberSearchCaptionValue : "nothing"
                                             ))))))))))))))))))))))))))))%>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `Dictionary` whose keys are your test strings, and whose values are your results.

e.g.

```
var sessionTypes = new Dictionary<string, string>()
sessionTypes.Add(
    "programmingLabels",
    (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["labelsNumberSearchCaptionValue"]);

//etc...
```

Then your code above becomes:

```
select name="searchTypeSelect" id="searchTypeSelect" size='1' class='searchUtilityMenu' >
    <option value='<%#
        sessionTypes.ContainsKey((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"]) ?
            sessionTypes[(string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"]] : 
            "nothing";
    %>' />
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd put that whole bit in a method that uses a switch, and call that. Something like:

```
<option value='<%# GetOption() %>' />
```

The method in code-behind:

```
public string GetOption()
{
    switch((string)HttpContext.Current.Session["whichMenu"])
    {
        case "programmingPLUSearch":
            return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["pluNumberSearchCaptionValue"];
        case "programmingLabels":
            return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["labelsNumberSearchCaptionValue"];
        // etc etc
        default:
            return "nothing";
    }
}
```

<strike>Nick Udell's suggestion is also a good idea to also implement next</strike>, but I'd use [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of ContainsKey. **UPDATE:** Actually, perhaps not. I'm thinking that these session/other variables might get updated often, and then such a dictionary would contain stale data. Of course you could maintain it, but then you basically would be doing twice the work.

I'd also put all these names of keys in a `static class` as `public const string` and use those instead of retyping/copy-pasting them when you need them in code.

Comment: If the variables are updated often, you could alter the value type of the dictionary to be an action that acquires the correct value, but I agree that at that point it is basically a switch statement anyway (although one that could be generated dynamically, perhaps).